# Css transform animation from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with a navigation bar that has slides a menu from right to left.
With my code, when the user picture is being clicked, it will show the menu.

So when it is loaded, menu is hidden and when it is clicked will be showed. I used to add class `hidden` and `show` to toggle to menu.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".img-profile").click(function(){
        $(".menu-wrapper").addClass("show");
    });
    $(".menu-bg").click(function(){
        $(".menu-wrapper").removeClass("show");
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.show{
    display: inline-block !important;
 }
 .hidden{
    display: none;
  }
```

The problem is it's not animating even if I added the `transition: all 0.2s linear 0s` and the transform from `250px` to `0`

```
.menu-wrapper > .login-menu{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 5;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
.menu-wrapper .show > .login-menu{
  transform: translateX(250px);
}
```

Also, I want to animate it on menu-close from right to left.

My full code is at **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8hzuj4nr/3/)**

Comment: this happens because your `.menu-wrapper` element is hidden using `display:none`, you need to change your html structure if you want to animate the menu i.e. get the `.login-menu` element outside of `.menu-wrapper`

Comment: can you update my jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the display CSS attribute does not trigger animations. Use the visibility attribute instead. This one triggers animations.

If you have good reason to use display (which is completely possible), you'll need to set the display attribute first to show the element, but keep the visibility on hidden. Set the visibility: visible attribute right after and the animation will be triggered.

Edit: I had a look at your fiddle. Don't use the .hidden class, because bootstrap sets display:none on .hidden elements. Just use the .show class alone, putting visibility:visible in the show class, and setting visibility:hidden on the .menu-wrapper element. Remove all the display:none lines in your CSS and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with this trick.

```
<header class="header">
<div class="container">
    <a class="logo" href="/"></a>
    <div class="login">
        <div class="img-profile" style="background-image: url('http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?width=100&height=100')"></div>

            <div class="login-menu">
                <div class="img-profile" style="background-image: url('http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?width=100&height=100')"></div>
                <p>Mark Zuckerberg</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Logout</button>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-bg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ececec;
}
.header > .container{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.logo {
    background: url("http://d12xrwn9fycdsl.cloudfront.net/static/images/sv_logo.png") no-repeat scroll center center / contain ;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 23rem;
    height: 100%;
}
.select-lang {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
}
.login{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.img-profile{
    background: no-repeat scroll center center / contain;
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
.login > .menu-wrapper{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.login-menu{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    right: -250px;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 5;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
}
.show{
  right: 0;
}
.hidden{
    right: -250px;
  }
.login-menu > .img-profile {
    border-radius: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}
.login-menu > p {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px 0 20px;
}
.menu-wrapper  > .menu-bg{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".img-profile").click(function(){
        $(".login-menu").addClass("show");
    });
    $(".img-profile").click(function(){
        $("body").removeClass("show");
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here https://jsfiddle.net/SkiWether/KFmLv/
this is working for me

```
$(".myButton").click(function () {

    // Set the effect type
    var effect = 'slide';

    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: $('.mySelect').val() };

    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 500;

    $('#myDiv').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
```